# Beam Center Range for FMCW radar

Tags: radar

I am provided with the following information:

```
     aCxyz: [3×10000 double]
       raw: [30000×10000 complex]
 Bandwidth: 3.6000e+09
       PRF: 833.3333
        Fs: 25000000
        fc: 3.4800e+10
chirp_rate: 3.0000e+12 [Cr]
         c: 3.0000e+8
```

The number of pulses is 10000 and the number of range samples is 30000
I understand the max distance of this FMCW radar can be determined using the beat frequency formula as shown,

Fbeat = Cr * (2 * target_dist / c)

Max distance: Fs/2 * 1/Cr * c/2 = 625m

I am trying to figure out what is the slant range distance to the beam center. Is it possible to find this distance based on the available information? I have attached an image below to showcase the geometry.
Any help or hints is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Depends what your specific situation is. If you have your position coordinates in some kind of Earth centric coordinate system, and you have a certain Earth model, then you should be able to find what the distance is from the antenna face to the ground.

Comment: I might have some misconceptions or logical flaws. But I want to expose my train of thought. If I were to use the coordinates with reference to the 5000th pulse, I have [0,113,34]. Assuming that the  [0,0,0] is the center of the scene and [0,113,34] radar coordinates. The slant range to the center would be 117m. The furthest ground range distance would be 624m or [0,624,0]. This would imply the swath along the range to be 2*(624-113)=1024m. Since 1024m seems unlikely, hence I was wondering if there was another way to find the scene center or hopefully correct my thinking about the other params